Llama3.2 fails to respond to simple text inputs when bounded with tool calling on LangGraph
I am following along a LangChain tutorial for LangGraph. They are using OpenAI models in the tutorial. However, I want to use my local Ollama models. I am using Llama 3.2 as that supports tool callings. However, when I bind tools to the chat object, llm, it does not respond to normal text inputs and only returns a tool response. If it is not bound with a tool, it does respond to regular messages I am not sure and I cannot figure out whether it is an issue of the LangChain class or the Llama 3.2 model. Any suggestions regarding a fix for this will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.
Following is the code -
from langchain_ollama import ChatOllama
from langgraph.graph import MessagesState
from langgraph.graph import StateGraph, START, END
from langchain_core.messages import HumanMessage


def multiply(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a * b


def tool_calling_llm(state: MessagesState):
    return {"messages": [llm_with_tools.invoke(state["messages"])]}


llm = ChatOllama(model="llama3.2")
llm_with_tools = llm.bind_tools([multiply])

builder = StateGraph(MessagesState)
builder.add_node("tool_calling_llm", tool_calling_llm)
builder.add_edge(START, "tool_calling_llm")
builder.add_edge("tool_calling_llm", END)
graph = builder.compile()

messages = graph.invoke({"messages": HumanMessage(content="hello")})
print(messages)


This is the print result -

{'messages': [HumanMessage(content='hello', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={}, id='b3e1122b-400b-4f6d-b323-0b67f2aa1441'), AIMessage(content='', additional_kwargs={}, response_metadata={'model': 'llama3.2', 'created_at': '2024-10-21T11:07:58.132452Z', 'message': {'role': 'assistant', 'content': '', 'tool_calls': [{'function': {'name': 'multiply', 'arguments': {'a': '2', 'b': '3'}}}]}, 'done_reason': 'stop', 'done': True, 'total_duration': 1372686042, 'load_duration': 30459500, 'prompt_eval_count': 156, 'prompt_eval_duration': 752771000, 'eval_count': 22, 'eval_duration': 584293000}, id='run-28808b40-51d2-40ee-a9bf-e048a009651c-0', tool_calls=[{'name': 'multiply', 'args': {'a': '2', 'b': '3'}, 'id': 'b45ba4cc-7610-4d1a-93bc-de4deb6e6c1d', 'type': 'tool_call'}], usage_metadata={'input_tokens': 156, 'output_tokens': 22, 'total_tokens': 178})]}


I have the same issue
Using LangChain (not LangGraph to keep it simple). and Llama 3.2 via Ollama. It always attempts to call a tool even for simple messages like "Hello"
Did you find an answer?

@LaurieYoung No, I didn't. The best thing I came up with was to separate greeting messages from queries and then calling the llm. I have been trying to find out if it's an Ollama thing or a Llama thing and so far I have not found an answer to that. Any chance you know the answer to this?

I found a few things

You need to use bigger LLama models to do tool calling and conversation at the same time (https://www.reddit.com/r/LocalLLaMA/comments/1ece00h/llama_31_8b_instruct_functiontool_calling_seems/) basically the 8B model (and the 3B 3.2) are too small to work out if they should respond with a text response or a tool, so they can only do one (I tested the 70B model and it also struggled)
This model has been fine tuned, and works quite well (https://ollama.com/library/llama3-groq-tool-use)


I also found comments suggesting that the .bind_tools uses a newer way of instructing the model to return a tool call, and than the older way - which is manually describing everything in the prompt, works well for all models

@LaurieYoung Thank you for sharing your findings. It's been a great help!
